# How to add class to current item in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I have HTML code is formatted via `ng-repeat`:

```
<div id="list">
<div class="item" ng-click="Select()"></div>
<div class="item" ng-click="Select()"></div>
<div class="item" ng-click="Select()"></div>
</div>
```

How I can add class to current `.item` where was called method `Select()` after response AJAX?

**Angular JS:**

```
$scope.function = Select() {
  Ajax () {
   response (){
     // Here add CSS class to clicked element .item
   }   
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do: `$scope.select= function() {`. Your ng-click is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Manipulating DOM from controller is bad practice & you shouldn't do that wherever you had directive like `ng-class`

Basically you need to use `ng-class` directive & selected property in each item to have a track of selected items.

**Markup**

```
<div class="item" ng-class="{selected: item.selected}" ng-repeat="item in items"></div>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.Select = function(item) {
  $http.get('url').success(function(){
     item.selected = true;
  })
}
```

Comment: @Hamed it will work for all item..as selected property inside `item` gets true then class gets added

Comment: @Hamed does it helped you?